# Is "restore purchases" feature mandatory to pass App Store review?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

While implementing In-App purchase features, do I have to serve option to **"restore purchases"** for the user, or this feature is only optional/suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to restore previously purchased content doesn't have to be explicitly exposed to the user.  In some of the apps my company has shipped, previously purchased content is restored when the user taps on the "Buy" button.

Our initial design had a separate "Restore Purchase" button, but our publisher insisted that we remove it and have everything go through the "Buy" button.

**Update:** This answer was correct at the time it was written.  Apple has since changed its policies.

Comment: If my app uses my own account system, I can always link the user purchase to the user account and provide access once the user logs in. Would it still be mandatory to implement StoreKit's restore purchase functionality?

Answer (score 4):

Its optional, but you should consider adding it since there are multiple reasons a user might want to have this option (eg. a failed backup or a freshly new device, I wouldn't want to get punished for this by the App developers)

Answer (score 2):

It's mandatory. My app is rejected because of this.

Here's apple message:

> Reasons for Rejection:
>
> Jul 30, 2012 06:24 PM. From Apple.
>
> We found that while your app offers In-App Purchase(s) that can be restored, it does not include the **required** "Restore" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App Purchase(s), as specified in Restoring Transactions section of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide:
>
> "...if your application supports product types that must be restorable, you must include an interface that allows users to restore these purchases. This interface allows a user to add the product to other devices or, if the original device was wiped, to restore the transaction on the original device."
>
> To restore previously purchased In-App Purchase products, it would be appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user.
>
> For more information about restoring transactions and verifying store receipt, please refer to the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Today it is nessesary. you MUST have this "button" if you has "in-app purchases"

Answer (score -1):

**No.**

I have apps released without restore purchases.

Comment: today it is necessary, if they approved your apps is because they didnt test the app carefully, but if you read the apple documentation, it is mandatory